# How can I easily create a for loop that only continues if the characters are parenthesis followed by integers in Python?

Tags: python, regex, special-characters

As you can already see, I'm fairly new to coding, specifically Python, and I was wondering how I could loop through a string only if the iteration is a parenthesis followed by integers?

I'm attempting to write a duplicate file finder, and when it comes to file names, I could have the same file copied and named slightly different iryan(1).mp4 and iryan(2).mp4, and using splitext[0] isn't enough for it to be detected as a duplicate. For now, I'm using os.stat().st_size to at least ensure they're the same size before diving into the filename comparison, but I'm struggling with ideas on how to only continue a for loop if the iteration is on an opening parenthesis and is followed by an integer?

Is "regex" something I should deep-dive into to solve this problem?

Comment: a) Yes, you should dive into the regex world - it massively widens your possibilities. b) An expression that would fulfill your conditions, could be `\(\d+\)`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a list of file names (it could also be any other [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)):

```
file_names = ['iryan.mp4', 'iryan(1).mp4', 'iryan(2).mp4']
```

You can do the following to find all the duplicate names:

```py
import re

# This regex only matches names that contain
# a number in brackets followed by `.mp4`
dup_regex = re.compile(r'\(\d+\)\.mp4$')

for duplicate in filter(dup_regex.search, file_names):
    print (duplicate)
```

#### Output

```
iryan(1).mp4
iryan(2).mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('\(\d+\)')
name = 'iryan(2).mp4'
if len(pattern.findall(name)):
    for..You loop here
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the regex command, your code might look something like this:

```
pattern = re.compile('\(\d+\)')
for f in files:
  if pattern.match(f):
    # duplicate file found...
   # do something
```

Another alternative is to use the `filter` function. That code might look something like this:

```
pattern = re.match('\(\d+\)')
filtered_files = filter(lambda f: p.match(f) is None, files)
for f in filtered_files:
  # load file
  # do something
```

The interesting thing here is that the `filter` function will return an iterator, which you can access easily in the for loop later. This avoids using the if statement in the for-loop, which could make your code look a little nicer.

This method will return to you all of the files without the parenthesis+number combination in them, giving you, ideally, all of the original non-duplicate files, and excluding all of the duplicates. If you want just the duplicates (files with names that contain the parenthesis+number combination), you can change the filter command to this:

```
duplicate_files = filter(p.match, files)
```

Comment: Thank you good sir! I watched an hour video on RegEx before viewing the answers I was getting here and I got your first version but I wasn't aware of the filter option lol. Thank you again for the explanation!